# Best approach for AIC model selection?

Tags: model-selection, model, aic

I am doing a study where I am trying to model how different factors affect polar bear movement. I would like to conduct model selection using AIC. So far, I believe I have two options:
 
1)    Put every variable I am studying into one giant model, and then conduct step-wise model selection. What I would design would be a multi-variate model like this:
 
Movement variable = x1*(length of the ice season) + x2*(mean temperature) + x3*(year) + etc.
 
2)    Construct a few different models with different “themes” like so:
 
-       “Temporal” model: movement = x1*(length of ice season) + x2*(year) + x3*(start of ice season)
-       “Biological” model: movement = x1*(age of bear) + x2*(number of cubs) + x3*(Sex of bear)
-       “Environmental” model: movement = x1*(temperature) + x2*(ice concentration)
 
Then, conduct AIC selection for each model individually. After that, take the variables that came out as significant, and then combine them into one final model. So for example, if length of the ice season is significant for the temporal model, age is significant in the biological model and temperature is significant for the environmental model, my final model would be:
 
Movement = x1*(length of ice season) + x2*(bear age) + x3*(temperature)
 
My current thought is that option 1 makes more sense and has less steps. However, I am testing for a LOT of variables (over 10) and have a small sample size (about 25 bears), and I have seen other students in my lab do this.
 
Which approach makes the most sense

Comment: Your question is hard to read because of the lack of formatting. However, the gist seems to be that you'd like to do model selection. In R, the [MuMIn](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/index.html) package has a function for automated model selection; it's called *dredge*. The function though comes with a warning that automatic model selection is not a great idea (see the documentation).

Comment: Is there an alternative to the automatic approach? You are the domain expert and you know a lot about bears. You can use this knowledge to constrain or guide the model selection process. For example, you might want to consider only models that include the factors known to have an effect on bear movement.